# 2015 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Biology's [1st moderator election](https://biology.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: Mad Scientist] [image: Chris] [image: WYSIWYG]

They've replaced [the pro tempore crew](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) — please thank both teams for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with the new crew as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.org/results/5259980127076352/0).

Comment: Awww yeah!  Congrats you three!

Comment: Yes thank you to the protem moderators, and congratulations to our three newly elected moderators. There was an excellent field of candidates, and I found it difficult to pick just three.

Comment: Congratulations you all! You will make a great moderator team.

Comment: I didn't get in! I quit biology stackexchange! Just joking - congrats all!

Comment: Congrats to the new moderators!

Comment: Congrats and all the best to the elected triplet! And @AliceD, sorry to see you miss out, at least in my case, you were my vote no. 3 to be honest!

Comment: @AliceD Ditto! (i.e., me too)

Comment: Congrats everyone!