# 2017 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Biology's [second moderator election](https://biology.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: AliceD]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Please also join in in thanking [Mad Scientist](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/6/mad-scientist) who is stepping down. In addition to winning the [first election](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3114/2015-community-moderator-election-results), Mad Scientist was also a [moderator *pro tempore*](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) and helped move this site from beta to graduation.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4840572787359744/0).

Comment: Congratulations @AliceD and welcome to the moderators team. Any many thanks to the other candidates in this election. Unfortunately there was only one spot to fill.

Comment: Let me be the first to say it: Congrats @AliceD!! I know you'll do an excellent job in this new role! :D (And thanks to MadScientist for all your hard work the last few years

Comment: Fine, I guess I got stuck being the second person to say it -_- ha. (Man, just saw the results too -- there was no doubt on this one! ;p). Glad we pulled out so many voters!!!

Comment: Congrats Christiaan!

Comment: @fileunderwater haha thanks so much. Good to see my name appear in full actually :) I'm really happy to join the mod team and I'll try to live up to MadScientist's great and long-standing work here at Biology

Comment: @theforestecologist - the large numbers of voters surely was fueled by your most excellent promotion add I'm sure. Kudos :)

Comment: @Chris many thanks for your warm welcome here and in the chats. I'm honored to join the mod team!

Comment: I wish to thank @MadScientist here for his long-standing contributions and making Biology.SE what it is today.

Comment: Whoa, I believe this is what people in political circles call a landslide; congrats and well wishes. I'm going to miss MadScientist.

Comment: @AliceD Congratulations :)

Comment: @WYSIWYG Thanks so much. I'm happy to have that diamond :-)

Comment: @AliceD PARTYYYYYYY!!!!!!!!!! Congrats :D

Comment: @another'Homosapien' - thanks mate. I'm really happy it turned out this way, the more since the other two candidates are superb folks too. But... [There can only be one](http://www.giantfreakinrobot.com/scifi/juan-carlos-fresnadillo-set-direct-highlander-remake.html)   >__<

Comment: @AliceD - Agreed that there were excellent candidates, but so happy to see your contributions recognized in this manner. Congrats!

Comment: @anongoodnurse - many thanks for these words and I am really happy I can join the mod team on Bio. Awesomeness!! I'm still actively using your way of formatting the references list so I am standing on the shoulders of giants :)

Comment: @AliceD - More like a short 'tiny person' (dwarf). But thanks. :)

Comment: @anongoodnurse - bodily physics are not the core of this site; it's all about brains here you know ;-)

Comment: @AliceD I pride myself with the memory of an elephant - user name changes or not... ;)

Comment: @fileunderwater impressive, very impressive. Although I do remember your profile pic is a hand- drawn image of a tree :-)

Comment: Congratulations!!
Hope for a great year ahead